# How to form SOQL query for multiple objects in salesforce

Tags: sql, salesforce, soql

There are 5 objects: `contact`, `account`, `account_contact__c`, `user`, `recordtype` in Salesforce.
Below is the SQL query which needs to be converted to Salesforce SOQL query

```
SELECT c.id,c.fname,c.lname,u.name, ac.desc, r.date 
FROM contact c 
LEFT JOIN user u on c.oid =u.sfid 
LEFT JOIN account_contact__c ac on c.sfid=ac.contact_id__c  
LEFT JOIN account a on a.sfid=ac.account_id__c 
LEFT JOIN recordtype r on a.recordtypeid =r.sfid and r.type=‘test’
```

I managed to join 2 objects but in the second table, I’m not able to add more than one field.

```
Select id,fname,lname 
from contact 
where id in (
   select contact_id__c from account_contact__c
)
```

If I try to add another `SELECT` statement inside `account_contact__c`, I am getting an error.

Comment: Is account_contact_c the first query? Why would you add another SELECT statement? Did you mean "in the second query" - is this the nested SQL? Certainly can't have a second field in that nested SQL. Show sample data as well as desired output as text tables .

Comment: @june7 contact is the first query. Other objects need to be joined to get few fields from them. Like name from user object, date from recordtype object.

Answer (score 0):

We don't know all your relations, for example Contact-User. What do you need? Contact's Owner? Customer/Partner Community user created out of that contact? Created By/Last Modified by User?

And the Account_Contact__c table looks weird, why didn't you use standard AccountContactRelation. Or even normally go "up" from Contact to Account.

Something like this could work but it really depends on what you need. And wit your custom table - no promise this compiles, you might have different field names.

"related list style" - you start from contact, go "down" to your weird custom relationship, then "up" from that relationship to account.

```
SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Owner.Name,
   (SELECT Id, Account__r.Id, Account__r.Name, Account__r.RecordType.Name)
FROM Contact
```

"normal style" - you start from your custom relationship table then go "up" to acc and con

```
SELECT Id,
    Contact__r.FirstName, Contact__r.LastName, Contact__r.Owner.Name,
    Account__r.Name, Account__r.RecordType.Name
FROM Account_Contact__c
```